# Android: Array Loop - next element only after first loop finish

Tags: android

I would like to initiate void function with Array element. Simple example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.seven_minutes);        
            Excercise();


 final String Array[] = {"e1","e2","e3"};

 for (int i = 0; i <  Array.length; i++ ){

    jump(Array[i]);

     }
}

private void jump (String i){

wait 30s;

}
```

How to make, that second [i] would be initiate only after jump (Array[i]) function is finished? Like after 30s of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that jump method executed in a different thread, you need to execute inside the UI thread (onCreate) a `join()` method, that allows a thread to wait the finish of another thread, until it can continue its execution.

However, this does not seems a good idea, since your UI thread will be blocked for too much time.

You should manage them asynchronously. There are a lot of ways you can do it. For example you can use `[AsyncTask][1]` that allows you to execute some code in background (inside `doInBackground`) and at the end of this code executed in background, will be executed some code in the UI thread (`onPostExecute`).
So, you can check your condition the first time, then call the AsyncTask, and in onPostExecute recheck the condition (Array.lenght < i), and if it is verified, you can relaunch the AsyncTask.